# I have a problem.I want to connect the backend server with the frontend server

Tags: java, server, backend

The backend server is realized using Java and the frontend server is realized using Angular.
Backend side in Java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class EmployeemanagementApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeemanagementApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter(){
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
    }
}
```

The problem occurs to `return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);`

Comment: You say where the problem occurs but not what the problem is. Please show the error

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it myself. The solution is to replace the 'corsFilter' method with the method below. I think it doesn't work because SpringBoot version has changed.
After implementing this method the program will work.

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {

        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
```